# Use a value in a cell as part of a sheet reference

Tags: excel

Hopefully this is simple and clear enough:

Sheets in spreadsheet are months: 01 ; 02 ; 03 ... 12

I have a chart output for all the sheets (months) that references specific cells in each sheet:

```
January      February     
='01'!$M$22   ='02'!$M$22   ...
```

When I add a new month I am copying the formula and replacing the month number in the formula.  How can I write a formula that references a value in a cell for that month.

```
             January                February     
             ='Cell Value'!M$22$    ='Cell Value'!M$22$
Cell value    01                    02                      ...
```

I want this so I can simply carry over the formula when I add a new month and not have to manually change the sheet value (01, 02, 03 ... 12)

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply done with the INDIRECT() function.

Give INDIRECT the address of a cell (calculated by simplifying an expression, such as pulling your sheet name string), and it resolves as the directed cell value.

So to get M22 of a given sheet, with sheets named "01"-"12" for months, type:

```
=INDIRECT($C$4&"!$M$22")
```

**EDIT - Note - I forgot the "!" in the first instance of this formula**

Also I've removed other methods of getting the sheet name, which will not work as your code is on a summary tab, not the sheet itself.

Comment: Thanks.  I would hardcode, but I need to perform this task for multiple rows.  It's time consuming.  The =INDIRECT($A$1&"$M$22") doesn't seem to work.  I am guessing because the formula isn't referencing the sheet with the 'sheet name'!cell location format?

Comment: @Ted please be more clear about where your data is contained - hard to tell what cell the formula will be in, and where the 'sheet name' is coming from.

Comment: Formula to pull value in C5 (this is the output I need) and this is in sheet name "YTD".  Sheet value reference in C4. Value I need spit out is in sheet "01" cell M22.  Need formula in sheet "YTD" to: ='value in C4 (sheet name)'!M22  ..  Hope that helps

Comment: Then simply change "A1" to "C4" in my formula above. See my new edits.

Comment: Nailed it with the ! added.  Thanks!